# How to import a non-eclipse project from clear case remote client sever?

Tags: eclipse, version-control, clearcase

The normal process to load project from ccrc sever is create a Base view on the local machine and mount a specific VOB in the CCRC sever. Then we can import the project in this VOB by going import -> Existing project from workspace.

But the problem is some of our developers are using eclipse as the IDE, and all the projects on the server vob do not include .project and .classpath, Eclipse cannot recognize a project without having the .project and .classpath files in it. I have tried a workaround which is create a new project having the same name as the project wanted to be imported, and then going import -> File System. This will copy the project into the workspace from your local view but not in the source control. So this will be a problem when checking in and out.

Could anyone tell me the correct why to do that? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to compare the content of your simple `.project` that you created in order to try and import in your Eclipse workspace, with one `.project` file already stored in CCRC.

You should see a `nature` element which add to the project the "version control" capability.
For instance, for Rational Method Composer, you would see:

```
<nature>com.ibm.rmc.library.persistence.distributed.project.MethodPluginProjectNature</nature>
```

(I am not sure of the exact nature used by a CCRC project)
See [this technote](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21441578) as an example, in which the .project is *manually* modified to look like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<projectDescription>
  <name>new_name</name>
  <comment></comment>
  <projects>
  </projects>
  <buildSpec>
  </buildSpec>
  <natures>
    <nature>com.ibm.rmc.library.persistence.distributed.project.MethodPluginProjectNature</nature>
  </natures>
</projectDescription>
```

Comment: Again, the `<nature>` element I show in the answer is for RMC, not CCRC. It is an example, in order to illustrate what it would look like, not a literal value to copy. You need to find a similar `<nature>` element value in one of your existing CCRC-managed Eclipse project.

Comment: I cannot catch what you have said. The projects on the CCRC server donot including .project and I just want to import an agnostic project on the CCRC server into eclipse.

Comment: @user1311839: then try your normal process you describe in your question on a dummy Eclipse project in order to import it in CCRC, just to see what the generated .project looks like.

Comment: I have found a way to do that. But thanks for your reply VonC